# How does DynamoDB calculate the size of a write?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB documentation from Amazon says:

> One write capacity unit represents one write per second for an item up
>   to 1 KB in size. If you need to write an item that is larger than 1
>   KB, DynamoDB must consume additional write capacity units.

But what exactly does a write mean? For example, I have an item with 2KB size. I need to update only 1 field, say, a number attribute in the item, which is surely less than 100 bytes. Does Amazon count this as 1 write unit or 2 write units? I think the total item size matters (which means 2 write units), but I just have to be sure.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of any read or write is the total size of the item regardless of how many attributes you read or write.

The only (sort of) exception is global secondary indexes, where the size of the read is the total size of only the attributes of the item that are projected into that index.